# Video fullscreen mode in dialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am using this code to open a fragmentdialog from a custom adapter:

```
HomeActivity activity = (HomeActivity) (context);
            FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            editor.putString("post_media", remainder);
            editor.apply();
            PostVideoFragment alertDialog = new PostVideoFragment();
            alertDialog.show(fm, "fragment_alert");
```

And this is the layout from the fragment dialog:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the code for the fragmentdialog:

```
public class PostVideoFragment extends DialogFragment {

    VideoView post_video;



    public static String MISDATOS= "MisDatos";

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String post_media;


    public static PostVideoFragment newInstance() {
        PostVideoFragment fragment = new PostVideoFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_video, container, false);




        prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MISDATOS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        editor = prefs.edit();


       post_media = prefs.getString("post_media", "no");

        String url = "https://f..postsmedia/";

        final VideoView videoView;
        videoView = (VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.video);
        videoView.setVideoPath(url+post_media);
        videoView.start();



        return v;
    }
}
```

The functionality is right, the video is played, but I would need to play it at full width when the screen is in landscape mode, now it is only shown in a very small mode.

Here is the output:

Portrait mode:

[image]

Landscape mode:

[image]

Comment: Did you try switching to LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout? It has worked for other people.Put your VideoView inside LinearLayout

Comment: @VedprakashWagh; i will try your proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onStart` of your `DialogFragment`, you can set the height and width to `MATCH_PARENT` like below:

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null)
    {
        int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        //You need to add below lines in order to show FullScreen VideoView without the status bar
        dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not found, says the exception, but it is on the given URL . :(

Comment: What exception are you getting? Did it work before you changed your code to this?

Comment: this is the exception:  W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open https://faro.red/movmap/administrar/application/admin/postsmedia/8Lo6H0mapas.mov: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://faro.red/movmap/administrar/application/admin/postsmedia/8Lo6H0mapas.mov

Comment: I guess the exception is not caused by your changes. I don´t know the reason, but prior to your changes it only worked once, then the exception arrised

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194602/discussion-between-vedprakash-wagh-and-mvasco).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem regarding the size of the dialog, what solved it for me was to define the size of the dialog with `LayoutParams` like this:

```
Window window = yourDialog.getWindow();
if (window != null) {
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());

//This makes the dialog take up the full width
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
window.setAttributes(lp);
}
```

---

**But why can't you just set your dialog to `match_parent` from the XML and end with it?**

It seems like the default dialog LayoutParams ( wrap_content,wrap_content ) overriding the LayoutParams  that in your XML (match_parent,match_parent).

This is why you could use a fixed size (150dp,150dp) and see your dialog size changing, but then your dialog will not be responsive so it's not a smart solution.